# Yagi elements connected to boom?

Tags: antenna-construction

I'm considering building this yagi for some local contests: http://www.i1wqrlinkradio.com/antype/ch90/chiave3.htm. The question is should the elements be electrically connected to the boom or not? I sort of hope that they should as it makes construction easier, and on this guy's 430MHz yagi he explicitly states that they should be, however no mention is made of that in the 2m yagi page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yep, they are.  Someone will give a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physically, it should make little difference - symmetry tells us that at the connection point, no potential can exist, and without potential, no current.

It's fairly common practice to build especially larger yagi-uda with the elements simply screwed into, welded onto or crimped into the boom for stability reasons.